# Миграции Symfony 3. (PostgreSQL). Проблема с diff

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony3, doctrine2, миграция

Всем привет.
Проект на Symfony 3 и PostgreSQL. При выполнении миграции способом:

1. `doctrine:migrations:diff`
2. `doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Создается миграция и выполняется. Все ок.
Но если в Entity указать схему - `@ORM\Table(name="public.user")`. То при последующих миграциях (я про использование diff) моя модель User будет добавляться в миграцию как будто бы нет такой таблицы в бд.
Я так понимаю diff не видит схему "public" в бд.

Ребята, в какую сторону копать? Перегуглил уже наверное все что можно и нельзя. Спасибо!

Comment: Решил проблему частично. Отказался от указывания "public". Но это до тех пор, пока не понадобится работать с другой схемой. `@ORM\Table(name="\`user\`")` - так работает все отлично.

Answer (score 2):

Имя схемы необходимо указывать [отдельным атрибутом `schema`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#table), доступен с версии `doctrine` 2.5, но для `symfony 3` это ограничение помнится уже не проблема в любом раскладе.

Т.е. вот так:

```
@ORM\Table(name="user", schema="public")
```

Для схемы `public` обычно можно явно и не указывать. Но зависит от настройки пользователя в базе `search_path`.

А вот поскольку `user` - слово зарезервированное, то, оказывается, доктрине это ещё специально надо объяснить с помощью специальных кавычек:

```
@ORM\Table(name="`user`")
```

Так по крайней мере [утверждает документация](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words). Теперь в запросах тоже должны экранироваться имена. Возможно это diff'у до кучи и не нравится.

---

PS: в `migrations:diff` для `postgresql` есть неприятный уже не первый год [открытый баг](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/1110#issuecomment-255765189), когда всегда вместо сообщения что ничего не изменено генерируется пустая миграция `up` и попытка создать схему public в `down`. В комментариях к этому багу я описал обходной способ решения.

Comment: По поводу пустой миграции понял, спасибо! А вот со схемами... Дело в том что я пробовал отдельным атрибутом писать, эффект тот же. Diff не видит таблицу со схемой и все (( если не использовать имя схемы - все ок. Но это необходимо, т.к. К примеру User зарезервированное слово. Да и в будущем планируется создание дополнительных схем. По этому и проблема (( спасибо за ответ!

Comment: С сущностями в отдельных схемах, не упомянутых в `search_path` проблем точно нет, это я в своё время проверял. С сущностями в public проблем тоже не было, для них просто не указывалась никакая схема и они нормально жили. Зарезервированные имена (а скорей всего вообще все имена) diff должен строить с именами в кавычках, т.е. `create table "user" ` и с этим проблем тоже соответственно нет (хотя это проверить мне сейчас уже негде)

Comment: Попробовал другую схему, в `search_path` ее нет. Та же проблема что и с `public`. Не видит он таблицы в бд ((

Comment: А я уж думал заставить меня относиться к этой поделке под названием доктрина ещё хуже чем есть не получится. И вот, получилось. Нашёл заметку про зарезервированные имена. Если diff не одумается - то надо будет ковырять его исходники.